# how to Fit image view in the Screen in all iPhoneScreens

Tags: ios, swift

I have created image-view programmatically with constraints

```
let imgName = "2017-01-18-2.png"
    let image = UIImage(named: imgName)
    let imgView = UIImageView(image: image!)

    imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 365, height: 667)
    view.addSubview(imgView)
```

But when im running in iPhone 5s its coming with full view 
[(Full view Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdJWm.png)
If I'm running in iPhone 7  its coming lil bit up 
[(LilbitUp Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKgcb.png)
I have searched all previous questions but all people saying create constraints in storyboard but I want to do with programatically If any help It would be appreciated Thank you in Advance

Comment: An iPhone 5 and an iPhone 7 have different size screens, so of course an image with a fixed size is not going to fill an iPhone 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-c

```
UIview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
imgView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.hight)
```

Comment: your giving iPhone 5s width and hight thats why ur image little bit up in iPhone 7s

Comment: Height become hard coated that's why its little  up

Comment: your Welcome @sam